# Role-based access control with REST (HTTP)?

Tags: json, http, authentication, rest, rbac

I'm creating a system with a JavaScript client that will communicate with the server over REST (HTTP)[JSON].

I am using [role-based access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) to manage the calls.

**Example**: [explicit URL will stay the same]

- Anonymous -> request `\`
- Server -> route to login form: `\login\`
- User (now with cookie!) -> request `\`

  - `if (user->role == "manager") return "\manager-homepage\";`
  - `else return "\homepage\";`

Since REST is stateless how would I go about managing this use-case?

Do I send the cookie with each request, and the returned HTTP status codes will tell the JS where to route?

*[Which would be rather inefficient + open to MITM attacks]*

Comment: THe title is wrong, access control is authorization and you are talking about authentication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not use a standard authentication scheme, such as [http digest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Example_with_explanation)?

**Example**: [from Wikipedia page]

> - The client asks for a page that requires authentication but does not provide a username and password. Typically this is because the user simply entered the address or followed a link to the page.
> - The server responds with the 401 "client-error" response code, providing the authentication realm and a randomly-generated, single-use value called a nonce.
> - At this point, the browser will present the authentication realm (typically a description of the computer or system being accessed) to the user and prompt for a username and password. The user may decide to cancel at this point.
> - Once a username and password have been supplied, the client re-sends the same request but adds an authentication header that includes the response code.
> - In this example, the server accepts the authentication and the page is returned. If the username is invalid and/or the password is incorrect, the server might return the "401" response code and the client would prompt the user again.
>
> Note: A client may already have the required username and password without needing to prompt the user, e.g. if they have previously been stored by a web browser.

See also this answer to a very similar question: [REST and authentication variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458482/rest-and-authentication-variants)

Depending on your desired security level, you could serve the whole thing over ssl. That will prevent mitm attacks.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know of that RFC. I've modified your answer including the methodology, can you accept my edits?